# Linq Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

I am trying to do this on a method which is basically a mapper - maps old categories List to a new List. The OldCategory has fewer properties.

```
return categories = from c in oldCategories select new Category 
{  
   CategoryName = c.CategoryName, 
   Id = c.CategoryId, 
   Teams = CombineTeam(c.Team, coreTeam)
};
```

Why can't I use CombineTeam method in the expression? Help appreciated. Thanks

**UPDATE**: Not working because c.Team is IQueryable and CombineTeam methods takes a List

Can anyone help me convert IQueryable to List within the expression?

Comment: Here is the method CombineTeam defined? How about the variable coreTeam?

Comment: Is oldCategories an object already in memory, or is it a Linq-to-Sql/Entities expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return categories = from c in oldCategories select new Category 
{  
CategoryName = c.CategoryName, 
Id = c.CategoryId, 
Teams = CombineTeam(c.Team.ToList(), coreTeam)
};
```